# Count elements of a list

Tags: list-manipulation, counting

Let's create a random list

```
n = 100;
data = Table[{RandomReal[{0, 2}], RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}, {i, 0, n}]
```

Now we divide the $(x,y)$ plane into four sectors with the center at (1,0)

```
ang1 = 45;
ang2 = 135;
m1 = Tan[ang1*Degree];
m2 = Tan[ang2 *Degree];
y1 = m1*(x - 1);
y2 = m2*(x - 1);
ls = Plot[{y1, y2}, {x, -2, 2}, 
    PlotStyle -> {{Magenta, Dashed, Thick}}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

My question is how to count how many random points is at every sector.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
n = 100;
data = Table[{RandomReal[{0, 2}], RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}, {i, 0, n}];

y1[x_] = x - 1;
y2[x_] = 1 - x;

Plot[{y1[x], y2[x]}, {x, -0.5, 2.5}, Epilog -> Point[data]]
```

[image]

```
selection = 
 Select[data, #[[2]] > y1[#[[1]]] && #[[2]] > y2[#[[1]]] &];


Plot[{y1[x], y2[x]}, {x, -0.5, 2.5}, Epilog -> Point[selection]]
```

[image]

```
Length[selection]
```

> 30

this code works for selection in all 4 sectors

```
s = Table[
Select[data, #[[2]]~op1~y1[#[[1]]] && #[[2]]~op2~y2[#[[1]]] &], 
{op1, {Greater, Less}}, {op2, {Greater, Less}}] // Flatten[#, 1] &;

Length /@ s
```

> {27, 25, 25, 24}

Comment: What about the criteria of the other three sectors?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z done

Answer (score 7):

```
data2 = GatherBy[data, Sign @ {#[[2]] - m1 (#[[1]] - 1), #[[2]] - m2 (#[[1]] - 1)} &];

Length /@ data2
(* {29, 20, 24, 28} *)

ListPlot[data2, AspectRatio -> 1, Epilog -> ls[[1]], BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large]]
```

[image]

To get just the counts, you can also use `Count` with `Sign`:

```
Count[Sign[{#2 - m1 (# - 1), #2 - m2 (# - 1)}] & @@@ data, #] & /@ Tuples[{1, -1}, 2] 
(* {24, 20, 29, 28} *)

Count[Sign[{#2 - y1 /. x -> #, #2 - y2 /. x -> #}] & @@@ data, #] & /@
  Tuples[{1, -1}, 2]
(* {24, 20, 29, 28} *)

{Row@{#}, 
    Count[Sign[{#2 - m1 (# - 1), #2 - m2 (# - 1)}] & @@@ data, #]} & /@
   Tuples[{1, -1}, 2] // 
 TableForm[#, TableHeadings -> {None, {"Signs", "Count"}}] &
```

[image]

or,  with `UnitStep`:

```
Count[UnitStep[{#2 - m1 (# - 1), #2 - m2 (# - 1)}] & @@@ data, #]& /@Tuples[{1, 0}, 2] 
(* {24, 20, 29, 28} *)

Count[UnitStep[{#2 - y1 /. x -> #, #2 - y2 /. x -> #}] & @@@ data, #] & /@
  Tuples[{1, 0}, 2] 
(* {24, 20, 29, 28} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can refine your list of data usind `Cases`

```
s1 = Cases[data, l_List /;
     (l[[1]] > 1) &&
      (l[[2]] > m2*(l[[1]] - 1)) &&
      (l[[2]] < m1*(l[[1]] - 1))
     ];
```

There are conditional pattern `l_List` which will be applied for elements of your `data` list. As result, you obtain following:

```
Show[
ListPlot@data,
ListPlot[s1, PlotStyle -> Red],
Plot[{y1, y2}, {x, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> {{Magenta, Dashed, Thick}}, 
AspectRatio -> 1]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

kglr's method can be greatly enhanced by using vectorization and [`Tally`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tally.html) or [`Counts`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Counts.html).

```
SeedRandom[0]
n = 1*^6;
data = {RandomReal[{0, 2}, n], RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n]}\[Transpose];

{m1, m2} = {1, -1};

(* kglr's code *)
Count[Sign[{#2 - m1 (# - 1), #2 - m2 (# - 1)}] & @@@ data, #] & /@ 
  Tuples[{1, -1}, 2] // RepeatedTiming

(* my refactoring *)
Sign[{#2 - m1 (# - 1), #2 - m2 (# - 1)}]\[Transpose] & @@ (data\[Transpose]) // 
  Counts // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {12.91, {249666, 249914, 250638, 249782}}
>
> {0.333, <|{-1, 1} -> 250638, {1, 1} -> 249666,
>           {-1, -1} -> 249782, {1, -1} -> 249914|>}
> ```

The output of `Counts` is an [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) which if desired can be used like:

```
<|{-1, 1} -> 250638, {1, 1} -> 249666, {-1, -1} -> 249782, {1, -1} -> 249914|> /@ 
 Tuples[{1, -1}, 2]
```

> ```
> {249666, 249914, 250638, 249782}
> ```